# Data is not saved in MS Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

I have a visual C# project and I'm trying to insert data in a MS Access Database when I press a button. Here is the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter adapter=new OleDbDataAdapter();
                adapter.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand();
                adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText =
                     "insert into Candidati values ('" + maskedTextBox1.Text.Trim() + "','" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox2.Text.Trim() + "', '" + textBox3.Text.Trim() + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(maskedTextBox2.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(maskedTextBox3.Text) + "')";
                con.Open();
                adapter.InsertCommand.Connection = con;
                adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Inregistrare adaugata cu succes!");
                maskedTextBox1.Text = null;
                maskedTextBox2.Text = null;
                maskedTextBox3.Text = null;
                textBox1.Text = null;
                textBox2.Text = null;
                textBox3.Text = null;
                maskedTextBox1.Focus();
            }
            catch (AdmitereException exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("A aparut o exceptie: "+exc.Message, "Eroare!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

The connection string is:

```
private static string connectionString;
        OleDbConnection con;
        public AddCandidati()
        {
            connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Admitere.mdb";
            con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Where `AddCandidati` is the form.
The data is not saved in the database, why? I have the .mdb file in the project folder. What I'm doing wrong? I did not got any exception when I pressed the button.

Comment: Get the string of the insert command and try running it directly inside access to make sure the query is valid.

Comment: Query is valid, if it was not valid i should got the exception in catch block

Answer (score -1):

Your insert command is wrong. You have to specify the names of the columns first, then you give the values for each of those columns.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

Comment: No, there is no need to specify the columns first. I changed with connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\Admitere.mdb";  (also, copied the database in D:\\) and now worked.

Comment: @qwerty Are you saying you solved the problem? If so, please either answer and mark it or delete it.